# Permission issue on Nautilus on mounted folder on 17.10

Tags: permissions, mount, nautilus, 17.10, nfs

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 and I have now a problem with the mounted folder from my NAS. I use NFS to mount it, here the fstab line:

`192.168.1.103:/volume1/music/  /media/Kaori/Music  nfs defaults,user,noauto,noatime,intr   0   0`

the folder has the correct permission rw for user, group and all. And using the terminal (zsh) I can create folder, delete/rename files etc... But with Nautilus, I have read only access.

I don't have this problem with the sub-folders. I also don't have this problem with a USB key.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you checked your umask settings for logins.def?